# Getting data from two tables where one table is independent of the other

Tags: mysql

EDIT: Let me start over since I can't remove my post

I have three tables

```
messages
messages_share
users
```

I have two queries

query (1) gets the data from table messages

```
SELECT 
    `messages`.*, `users`.`uid`, `users`.`username`, `users`.`full_name`, `users`.`profile` 
FROM 
    `messages`
LEFT JOIN
    `users` ON `messages`.`owner_id`=`users`.`uid`
WHERE 
    `messages`.`to_id` IN ($ids) 
ORDER BY 
    `messages`.`time` DESC 
LIMIT 
    $start, $min
```

query (2) gets the data from messages_share

```
SELECT 
    `messages`.*, `messages_share`.*, `users`.`uid`, `users`.`username`, `users`.`full_name`, `users`.`profile` 
FROM 
    `messages_share`
LEFT JOIN
    `users` ON `messages_share`.`share_owner_id`=`users`.`uid`
LEFT JOIN
    `messages` ON `messages`.`share_message_id`=`messages`.`id`
WHERE 
    `messages_share`.`share_to_id` IN ($ids) 
ORDER BY 
    `messages_share`.`time` DESC 
LIMIT 
    $start, $min
```

I need to combine these queries together such that depending on which table it grabs from, the LEFT JOIN users gets pulled from the correct table, and the ORDER BY gets sorted by both messages and messages_share

The sudo query should look like this

```
SELECT 
    if(table_we_are_pulling_from=`messages_share`) 
         `messages_share`.*, 
    `messages`.*, `users`.`uid`, `users`.`username`, `users`.`full_name`, `users`.`profile`
FROM    
    `messages_share`,
    `messages`
if(table_we_are_pulling_from=`messages_share`) 
    LEFT JOIN `users` ON `messages_share`.`share_owner_id`=`users`.`uid`
else if(table_we_are_pulling_from=`messages`)
    LEFT JOIN `users` ON `messages`.`owner_id`=`users`.`uid`
WHERE
    if(table_we_are_pulling_from=`messages_share`) 
        `messages_share`.`share_to_id` IN ($ids)
    else if(table_we_are_pulling_from=`messages`)
        `messages`.`to_id` IN ($ids) 
ORDER BY 
    `messages`.`time` DESC
    `messages_share`.`share_time` DESC  
LIMIT 
    $start, $min
```

Comment: what do you want it to be?

Comment: let me edit my post so I can make more sense

Comment: I'm still not sure about why do you want to combine these queries, please mention what result you want at the end.

Comment: added how the query should behave like

Comment: Man, you made it really hard to understand. The thing that I could understand, I don't think that you can do in one single query..
you might have to find a way like **union two queries** or **merging the result arrays**

Comment: An sqlfiddle would probably help.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PHP, you can simply build this query dynamically.

```
$table_we_are_pulling_from = '`messages_share`'; //or `messages`
$other_table = '`messages`';
$table_id = '`share_owner_id`'; // or '`owner_id`'
$to_id = '`share_to_id`'; // or '`to_id`';
$message_time = '`share_time`'; 
$query = " SELECT $table_we_are_pulling_from.*, `users`.`uid`, `users`.`username`, `users`.`full_name`,     `users`.`profile`
FROM    
    $table_we_are_pulling_from
LEFT JOIN `users` ON $table_we_are_pulling_from.$table_id = `users`.`uid`
WHERE
    $table_we_are_pulling_from.$to_id IN ($ids)
ORDER BY 
    $table_we_are_pulling_from.$messages_time DESC  
LIMIT 
    $start, $min
```

Another option, if you're doing OOP, is to build an interface, implement it with two objects, and based on criteria that you set elsewhere, the object that will return the correct query will be selected.  For instance,

```
interface Messages { public function getUsersQuery(); }
class NormalMessages implements Messages {
    public function getUsersQuery() { //return query for regular messages }
}
class SharedMessages implements Messages {
    public function getUsersQuery() { //return query for shared messages }
}
```

Then, in your code...

```
if (//some condition) $messages = new SharedMessages();
$query = $messages->getUsersQuery();
```